# MySQL find missing combinations between two columns

Tags: mysql

I'm running in MySQL, I have a table output as destinations(a,b,c) as below

```
columnstart  columnend
a             b
a             c
b             a
b             b
b             c
c             a
```

Now I'm trying to get destinations which are not listed as below outputs

```
columnstart   columnend
a             a
c             b
c             c
```

Is there any ways to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Can you give us example input, and the output it should give?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following is a **Generalized Approach**:

- We get unique values out of `columnstart` and `columnend` in two separate Select queries, and do a `CROSS JOIN` between them, to get all possible combinations (Cartesian product) in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Now, just `LEFT JOIN` the Derived Table resultset with your main table, using `columnstart` and `columnend`.
- Find the **combinations missing from your main table**, by using `is null` condition on the rightmost table columns (your main table columns).

Try the following (**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c5bd/1)**):

```
SELECT dt.columnstart, 
       dt.columnend 
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.columnstart, t2.columnend FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT columnstart FROM your_table) AS t1 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT columnend FROM your_table) AS t2 
) AS dt 
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t3 
  ON t3.columnstart = dt.columnstart AND 
     t3.columnend = dt.columnend 
WHERE t3.columnstart IS NULL AND 
      t3.columnend IS NULL
```

Comment: +10 yes this is the same approach I would use. Cartesian product of all possible combinations, with an anti-join to eliminate combinations that do exist, leaving combinations that do not exist.