# Check if a possible combination does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a `table A` with columns `COL_1` and `COL_2`

- `COL_1` contains an id for a deck of cards (52).
- `COL_2` contains the combination, but without itself

How can I check if a combination like `3 & 4` is not present, automatically?

For example, for 4 cards and relation 3=4 is missing here:

```
  CREATE TABLE deck(
  id int,
  col_1 int,
  col_2 int
);

INSERT INTO deck VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 4),
(4, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 3),
(6, 2, 4),
(7, 3, 1),
(8, 3, 2),
(9, 4, 1),
(10, 4, 2),
(11, 4, 3)
```

I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM desk WHERE col_2 NOT IN (
SELECT col_1 FROM deck GROUP BY col_1)
```

but I think this should be on every col_1 item.

Comment: Does your combo column contain an integer or a varchar, so 1 | 1=2 or 1 | 2?

Comment: @GRIV i just update my question

Comment: How do you know that 3 and 4 should be a row? Something seems a bit off or over simplified here. Why would you not just store the values 1,2,3,4? Coming up with all combinations is painless from that and you don't need to store all of them.

Comment: @SeanLange the problem is very very expense, I used a dummy example with deck of cards because is a similar example that everyone can follow without having to explain the entire problem. I have already the data, I need to find the missing combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific approach for doing this, which is finding the:

> Cartesian product of all possible combinations, with an anti-join to
> eliminate combinations that do exist, leaving combinations that do not
> exist.

with an additional condition in the `WHERE` clause to only display specific missing values that you need using `WHERE a.col_1 != a.col_2`; this will scale your entire *deck*.

See more from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728328/mysql-find-missing-combinations-between-two-columns).

Then you can optionally perform a `UNION` to add the missing rows to your current table's result set.

I've also added a `Y/N` flag to indicate the missing row.

```
SELECT id, 
       col_1, 
       col_2, 
       'N' AS missing_value 
FROM deck
UNION
SELECT a.id,
       a.col_1,
       a.col_2,
       'Y' AS missing_value
FROM 
(
  SELECT b.id, b.col_1, c.col_2 FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id, col_1 FROM deck) AS b 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id, col_2 FROM deck) AS c 
) AS a 
LEFT JOIN deck AS d 
  ON d.col_1 = a.col_1 AND 
     d.col_2 = a.col_2 
WHERE d.col_1 IS NULL AND 
      d.col_2 IS NULL 
      AND a.col_1 != a.col_2
```

**Result:**

| id | col_1 | col_2 | missing_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | N |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | N |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | N |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | N |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | N |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | N |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | N |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | N |
| ***1*** | ***3*** | ***4*** | ***Y*** |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | N |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | N |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | N |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/adrBittX).

Comment: with 1600 records after 300 secs time out.

Comment: Even without the UNION? When you try and retrieve the missing values by themselves?

Comment: Will Id always be 1? Try limiting your data set to a single Id # or col_1 value and see if that works. Then, you may need to increase your [remote query timeout option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) or disable it completely by setting it to 0 and see if that works. Some other tips [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/troubleshoot-query-timeouts). Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: id is an autoincremental pk

Comment: I would try and isolate a missing col_1 value (I.e. 3 above) just to see if the query returns anything at all. If it does, remove your timeout mentioned in my previous post. You may have to wait a bit but it should return the proper rows.

Answer (score 1):

As you are searching all number, it would be best to use CTEs to generate a number column, with all number(assuming that `MAX(col_1)` will give that

The rest is simple logic, but it will find also if in col_1 are missing numbers and find them

But with bigger numbers this could get a little time consuming

```
  CREATE TABLE deck(
  id int,
  col_1 int,
  col_2 int
);

INSERT INTO deck VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 4),
(4, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 3),
(6, 2, 4),
(7, 3, 1),
(8, 3, 2),
(9, 4, 1),
(10, 4, 2),
(11, 4, 3)
```

```
11 rows affected
```

```
DECLARE @end INTEGER ;
SET @end = (SELECT MAX(col_1) FROM deck);  
WITH Nums AS
(
  SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects 

),
 CTEnum as (
SELECT n FROM Nums 
WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND @end
)
SELECT  L1.n,L2.n  FROM (CTEnum L1 CROSS JOIN CTEnum L2) 
  LEFT JOIN deck ON l2.n = Deck.col_2 and l1.n = Deck.col_1
WHERE Deck.id IS NULL
```

| n | n |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rOte0GZn)